# Equivalent of System.Windows.Forms.Cursor in Web Application(Asp.Net)

Tags: asp.net

I have a code in windows application now i am trying to implement in web
     Application but it is showimg that it ths no cursor class
     (System.Windows.Forms.Cursor )so..wat is the equivalent in web application.

```
 Here is my code

      private void btnGo_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        Application.DoEvents();


        // Load the images.
        Bitmap bm1 =  (Bitmap) (Image.FromFile(txtFile1.Text));
        Bitmap bm2 =  (Bitmap) (Image.FromFile(txtFile2.Text));

        // Make a difference image.
        int wid = Math.Min(bm1.Width, bm2.Width);
        int hgt = Math.Min(bm1.Height, bm2.Height);
        Bitmap bm3 = new Bitmap(wid, hgt);

        // Create the difference image.
        bool are_identical = true;
        int r1;
        int g1;
        int b1;
        int r2;
        int g2;
        int b2;
        int r3;
        int g3;
        int b3;
        Color eq_color = Color.White;
        Color ne_color = Color.Transparent;
        for (int x = 0; x <= wid - 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= hgt - 1; y++)
            {
                if (bm1.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(bm2.GetPixel(x, y)))
                {
                    bm3.SetPixel(x, y, eq_color);


                }
                else
                {
                    bm1.SetPixel(x, y, ne_color);
                    are_identical = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Display the result.
        picResult.Image = bm1;

        Bitmap Logo = new Bitmap(picResult.Image);
        Logo.MakeTransparent(Logo.GetPixel(1, 1));
        picResult.Image = (Image)Logo;

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        if ((bm1.Width != bm2.Width) || (bm1.Height != bm2.Height))
        {
            are_identical = false;
        }
        if (are_identical)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The images are identical");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The images are different");
        }

        //bm1.Dispose()
        // bm2.Dispose()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you can't access to cursor, because it runs on server side.. You can remove from your code.

Also the Application.DoEvents(); and MessageBox.Show() doesn't work on web environment.